firestore with cloud function: how to delete documentId from lists in other path?
I am building a sns type of app where user can write a post and other users can hit 'like' button to like the post.
This is data structure I have in firestore.
/root
    /users (collection)
        /user_id_a (document with fields)
            - user_id_a
            - user_name_aa
            /liked_list (collection)
                /one_unique_doc (only document under liked_list collection)
                    - liked_list // <-(a) store document_ids of posts that user likes as an array.

    /post_types (collection)
        /type_a
            /posts
                /post_id_c (document with fields)
                - post_id_c
                /liked_by_list
                    /one_unique_doc (only document under like_by_list collection)
                        - target
                        - liked_by_list // <-(b) store user_uids of users who liked this post.  

when a user hit like button then two fields are written where I marked as (a) and (b).
one place is for user to know what posts he/she has liked. the other place is for post to recognize who liked current post.
Now, I want to delete post's documentId from (a) when the post owner delete his/her post and I want to achieve this using cloud functions for firebase.
how can I achieve this with cloud functions for firebase? I will appreciate it if any code snippet is provided either in javascript or typescript.
just in case it might be good start, here is what I have to start cloud functions with typescript below. Since this is my first time trying to write cloud functions, this might not be correct though.
export.onPostDeleted = onDocumentDeleted("path/to/posts/{postDocumentId}", (event) => {
    let users = await admin.firestore()
        .collectionGroup("likedList")
        .where("liked_list", 'array-contains', event.params.postDocumentId)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
            snapshot.docs.map((d) {
                return d.reference.parent.parent;
            });
        });
});

